# Using java write CSV file from database table and without letting data values converted to scientific format (9.97E-05)?

Tags: java, database, csv

I want to store huge data values in Numeric form only in CSV file, I am fetching data from a Database Table and writing to CSV using CSVwriter in my Java code.

```
CSVWriter wr1;
wr1 = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csvfilepath), ',');
wr1.writeAll(rs, true, true);
```

rs is the result set returned after triggering SQL query

while storing the data it converts some columns to scientific and data appears like "9.97E-05" which was supposed to be like "0.0000997070398697983"

I want my data to be stored as "0.0000997070398697983"

data appears like "9.97E-05" as scientific cell format type.

Comment: The default implementation probably uses `toString()` which results in scientific notation.  Try setting a `ResultSetHelper` which knows how to format the data.

Comment: Thanks, @Andrew I have used ResultSetHelper before writing data to CSV